# Mac Contacts syncs it's info TO iCloud -- but it won't GATHER info FROM iCloud

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, data-synchronization, contacts

So my iPhone contacts are all syncing to iCloud, and the contacts on my Mac are syncing to iCloud -- but I can't get my contacts from my iPhone TO my Mac via iCloud. It's like a one-way relationship. I've unchecked and rechecked everything, trying to re-sync, but my Mac just refuses to update and add those iCloud contacts to my Mac. It's like someone who talks all day, but refuses to listen to anyone.
Incidentally, if I make a contact change on my Mac, such as updating my user picture, the picture changes on the iPhone contact. So it's really just an unhealthy relationship they have.

Comment: Which iPhone and what version of macOS.  I had a similar issue, but with Outlook.com.  My fix was to delete all the accounts and re-add them.  For some reason, that cleared things up.

Comment: it's an iPhone 8 and I'm using Catalina This issue has persisted over a couple of years and I decided to try and solve it! But... thus far, unsuccessfully